# Response object templates in Karate

Tags: karate

Is there a way to create a template structure of a response object, that ignores content of fields? I'm in this instance interested in verifying that all relevant field names are present, regardless of related data.
A dataless version of [Templates](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) that can be used in Scenario Outline would be great.

For the curious soul, I'm verifying API docs.

Example response to verify structure of:

```
"Clinics": [
{
  "ClinicId": 1212,
  "MondayOpen": null,
  "MondayClose": null,
  "TuesdayOpen": null,
  "TuesdayClose": null,
  "WednesdayOpen": null,
  "WednesdayClose": null,
  "ThursdayOpen": null,
  "ThursdayClose": null,
  "FridayOpen": null,
  "FridayClose": null,
  "SaturdayOpen": null,
  "SaturdayClose": null,
  "SundayOpen": null,
  "SundayClose": null,
}]
```

I'm not interested in the value of ClinicId or the other fields.
I'd like to know if the field ClinicId, MondayOpen, and so on is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand but let me try. If you have a JSON as follows:

```
* def json = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'ban' }
```

You can use the `#present` marker as follows:

```
* match json == { foo: '#present', baz: '#present' }
```

Now, it sounds like you want to dynamically determine the keys you want:

```
* def keys = ['foo', 'baz']
```

You can easily programmatically create the needed template:

```
* def template = {}
* eval karate.forEach(keys, function(k){ template[k] = '#present' })
* match json == template
```

Hope that helps ! Note that `karate.forEach()` is new in 0.8.0 - and you can use 0.8.0.RC9 in the mean-time.

If you refer these examples, you may get more ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/search-complex.feature#L27

Comment: Using #present for matching presence of the field/key did the trick. Could you perhaps elaborate how to use #present for the response objects at the root? Testing if Clinics[] are present.

Comment: Figured it out with a little toying around: * match response contains { "Clinics" : #present }. Pretty damn awesome tool!

Comment: in the upcoming 0.8.0 you will be able to do `* match response.Clinics == '#present'` as an alternative - which some people prefer.